# Azure AI Document intelligence, getting InvalidContentSourceFormat error

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-form-recognizer

Currently i am working with azure ai document intelligence form recognizer. I have written the logic and hit my api. My api will  take azure form recognizer endpoint, and apikey to connect. But i am getting below error. Please help to solve on this.

```java
com.azure.core.exception.HttpResponseException: Status code 400, "{"error":{"code":"InvalidArgument","message":"Invalid argument.","innererror":{"code":"InvalidContentSourceFormat","message":"Invalid content source: Url must be http or https."}}}"
    at com.azure.ai.formrecognizer.documentanalysis.implementation.util.Transforms.getHttpResponseException(Transforms.java:276) ~[azure-ai-formrecognizer-4.0.8.jar:4.0.8]
    at com.azure.ai.formrecognizer.documentanalysis.DocumentAnalysisClient.analyzeDocument(DocumentAnalysisClient.java:332) ~[azure-ai-formrecognizer-4.0.8.jar:4.0.8]
    at com.azure.ai.formrecognizer.documentanalysis.DocumentAnalysisClient.lambda$analyzeActivationOperation$2(DocumentAnalysisClient.java:302) ~[azure-ai-formrecognizer-4.0.8.jar:4.0.8]
    at com.azure.ai.formrecognizer.documentanalysis.DocumentAnalysisClient.lambda$beginAnalyzeDocumentFromUrlSync$0(DocumentAnalysisClient.java:181) ~[azure-ai-formrecognizer-4.0.8.jar:4.0.8]
    at com.azure.core.util.polling.SimpleSyncPoller.<init>(SimpleSyncPoller.java:65) ~[azure-core-1.40.0.jar:1.40.0]
    at com.azure.core.util.polling.SyncPoller.createPoller(SyncPoller.java:127) ~[azure-core-1.40.0.jar:1.40.0]
    at com.azure.ai.formrecognizer.documentanalysis.DocumentAnalysisClient.beginAnalyzeDocumentFromUrlSync(DocumentAnalysisClient.java:174) ~[azure-ai-formrecognizer-4.0.8.jar:4.0.8]
    at com.azure.ai.formrecognizer.documentanalysis.DocumentAnalysisClient.beginAnalyzeDocumentFromUrl(DocumentAnalysisClient.java:157) ~[azure-ai-formrecognizer-4.0.8.jar:4.0.8]
    at com.azure.ai.formrecognizer.documentanalysis.DocumentAnalysisClient.beginAnalyzeDocumentFromUrl(DocumentAnalysisClient.java:113) ~[azure-ai-formrecognizer-4.0.8.jar:4.0.8]
```

I have tried by checking all possible to ways to findout, couldn't able to find.
Even i tried to check azure documentation and support faq.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided error log, it indicates that the URL you are passing to the `beginAnalyzeDocumentFromUrl` method is not in the correct format.

As you are using `beginAnalyzeDocumentFromUrl`, the URL input must be in the format of `http` or `https`.

To fix the issue please check your source input format and you can check below sample input for reference and testing:

> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-REST-api-samples/master/curl/form-recognizer/sample-layout.pdf

I was able execute `beginAnalyzeDocumentFromUrl` method with above sample URL.
[image]

For more details regarding implementation, you can check this [documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/document-intelligence/quickstarts/get-started-sdks-rest-api?view=doc-intel-3.1.0&pivots=programming-language-java#general-document-model)

Comment: Thank you,suggestion was worked.I have one more query that, currently azure ai form recognizer is not supporting .csv or excel files,do we have any approach to read key value pairs or table structures from excel files?other than converting excel into pdf (as it includes 3rd party library call involves, in project we cannot call third party library due to security reasons).